# Rails - Do not send message if user not approved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

I have a rails app and user model. User can sign up the form but the admin should approved his/her profile first. So I have status :boolean default to false column in user model. You can search user on search field. I do not show those users if status column is false.

**BUT**
Lets say user with an id 5 is not approved meaning status column is false.

if user types .../en/users/5

it goes to that url and can send messages. How should I do that so they cant send email.

I should have something like;

```
def check_user(user)
  if user.status
     redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

and where should I put this?. To user controller#show action as before filter?

Comment: callbacks are ok, but if you want to have lost of such checks, consider [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) - best you could find for such needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends on your needs. If you only need this check for disallowing this specific action, then put to #show method like you suggested. 
It might happen you want to protect all user controller actions (not just #show). On the other approach, you may want not to redirect user (it's not informative), but show the view and hide send email portion of it (put some warning message instead). Make sure you protect send email method!

Also, you may even want to put the above logic to ApplicationController, to prevent not approved users to do any action - if that matches your needs

Answer (score 1):

You have to put in the Application controller like

```
class Api::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
    before_action :check_user

   def check_user
     # get your user here with the help of param
     if !user.status
       redirect_to root_path
    end
   end
end
```

Comment: it will redirect to root path if the status is `true` :) not what OP looked for. `redirect_to root_path unless current_user.status`